# "ValueError: embedded null character" when using open()

Tags: python

I am taking python at my college and I am stuck with my current assignment.  We are supposed to take 2 files and compare them. I am simply trying to open the files so I can use them but I keep getting the error `"ValueError: embedded null character"`

```
file1 = input("Enter the name of the first file: ")
file1_open = open(file1)
file1_content = file1_open.read()
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Where are the files coming from?

Comment: My teacher added tester files to be used when running the program. The first file in one of the testers that gives me the error is "Tests/4-test.txt"

Comment: You have a null byte embedded in the string which won't work using python, you need to remove the null bytes/s. What OS are you using?

Comment: If you are using linux try  `tr -d '\000' < Tests/4-test.txt  > Tests/4-test_cleaned.txt` and use `test_cleaned.txt`

Comment: I'm using windows 10. I'm also using python 3.5

Comment: Then you will need to find a way to remove the null bytes using some windows software, I am not familiar with windows but this blog post should help http://security102.blogspot.ru/2010/04/findreplace-of-nul-objects-in-notepad.html Also are you sure the data did nto get corrupted somehow?

Comment: @Erica try:   file1_open = open(file1, 'rb') an let us know

Answer (score 20):

It seems that you have problems with characters "\" and "/". If you use them in input - try to change one to another...

Comment: This answer was downvoted for the wrong reasons as this possibly resolves the error. This answer worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Default encoding of files for Python 3.5 is 'utf-8'.

Default encoding of files for Windows tends to be something else.

If you intend to open two text files, you may try this:

```
import locale
locale.getdefaultlocale()
file1 = input("Enter the name of the first file: ")
file1_open = open(file1, encoding=locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
file1_content = file1_open.read()
```

There should be some automatic detection in the standard library.

Otherwise you may create your own:

```
def guess_encoding(csv_file):
    """guess the encoding of the given file"""
    import io
    import locale
    with io.open(csv_file, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read(5)
    if data.startswith(b"\xEF\xBB\xBF"):  # UTF-8 with a "BOM"
        return "utf-8-sig"
    elif data.startswith(b"\xFF\xFE") or data.startswith(b"\xFE\xFF"):
        return "utf-16"
    else:  # in Windows, guessing utf-8 doesn't work, so we have to try
        try:
            with io.open(csv_file, encoding="utf-8") as f:
                preview = f.read(222222)
                return "utf-8"
        except:
            return locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
```

and then

```
file1 = input("Enter the name of the first file: ")
file1_open = open(file1, encoding=guess_encoding(file1))
file1_content = file1_open.read()
```

Comment: I am not allowed to import anything into my program

Answer (score 7):

Try putting r (raw format).

`r'D:\python_projects\templates\0.html'`

Answer (score 5):

On Windows while specifying the full path of the file name, we should use double backward slash  as the seperator and not single backward slash.
For instance, C:\\FileName.txt instead of C:\FileName.txt

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when copying a file to a folder that starts with a number. If you write the folder path with the double \ sign before the number, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The first slash of the file path name  throws the error.

Need Raw, r 
Raw string

```
FileHandle = open(r'..', encoding='utf8')
```

FilePath='C://FileName.txt' 
FilePath=r'C:/FileName.txt'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to bytes data that needs to be decoded.

When you insert a variable into the interpreter, it displays it's repr attribute whereas print() takes the str (which are the same in this scenario) and ignores all unprintable characters such as: \x00, \x01 and replaces them with something else.

A solution is to "decode" file1_content (ignore bytes):

```
file1_content = ''.join(x for x in file1_content if x.isprintable())
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error with the following code:

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile("C:\local_files\REPORT.zip",mode='w') as z:
    z.writestr(data)
```

It was happening because I was passing the *bytestring* i.e. data in `writestr()` method without specifying the name of file i.e. `Report.zip` where it should be saved.
So I changed my code and it worked.

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile("C:\local_files\REPORT.zip",mode='w') as z:
    z.writestr('Report.zip', data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this `D:\path\0.html` try this `D:/path/0.html` Reason of error is python interpret \0 instead of path string.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to open a file then you should use the path generated by `os`, like so:

```py
import os
os.path.join("path","to","the","file")
```