# Using Tabula to pull tables out pdf

Tags: tabula, palantir-foundry

We have standard reports uploaded as PDFs on a daily basis. In the PDFs are some tables that we want to pull into datasets.
I have tabula imported in code repositories but I can't seem to get code repositories to bring in the PDF.

I recieve this error:

"Error loading inputs"

"{"message":"Unable to resolve alias","alias":"/US Office/COO/pdf_tests/test.pdf","fallbackBranches":["master"]}"

And this is the very basic code I am using:

```
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output
import tabula


@transform_df(
    Output("/US Office/COO/pdf_tests/datasets/pdf_read"),
    source_df=Input("/US Office/COO/pdf_tests/test.pdf"),
)
def compute(source_df):
    df = source_df
    df = tabula.read_pdf(df, pages='all')
    return df
```

I can easily make tabula output a csv with my local python install just not in Foundry.
Any help you can give would be great as I am very new to Palantir foundry and code repositories.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

First things first, Thank you to fmsf for getting me goin in the right direction.

Next, The Answer:

I was able to get it to work once I got rid of the .read() in the result variable.
Tabula want to see a path(which is hard in this situation) or a Python file like object which is what the .open returns. below is the code that works and will hopefully help to get others started.

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
import tabula
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
import pandas as pd


@transform(  #note that this is @transform and not @transform_df
    out=Output("/US Office/COO/pdf_tests/outdata"),     # The output datasheet path
    raw=Input("/US Office/COO/pdf_tests/datasets/dataset_pdf"),  # path to the input raw datasheet that contains the PDF
)
def compute(ctx, raw, out):
    rows = []
    result = []     # define results list
    fs = raw.filesystem()   # variable to make accsessing the datasheet filesystem easy
    latest_file = 'test.pdf'    # the name of the pdf inside the dataset
    df_schema = StructType([        # defining the spark schema
        StructField("system", StringType(), True),
        StructField("status", StringType(), True),
        StructField('date', StringType(), True),
        StructField('user', StringType(), True),
        StructField('id', StringType(), True)
        ])
    with fs.open(latest_file, mode='rb') as f:   # with statement that opens the pdf as f. rb essential as it has to be opened as a raw binary file
        result = tabula.read_pdf(f, pages='all', multiple_tables=True)   # basic tabula read function that generates a list of tables within another list.

    rows.append(result[0])  # adds the list of tables into the rows list
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows[0])  # Creates a pandas dataframe using the first table in the pdf
    df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(df, schema=df_schema)    # casts the pandas df to a pyspark df using the defined schema
    out.write_dataframe(df)  # writes the pyspark dataframe to the ouput dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

The part that you are missing is the way to ingest and parse the PDF. Lets go step by step:

Your `Input` can only consume datasets and they need to have at least one valid transaction on the fallbackBranch (normally `master`)

You can achieve this by using data connection to ingest your dataset, alternatively you can create a dataset manually, and drop your pdf into its contents.

Then the file will show up, like in this example of an ingest from a public piece of data:

[image]

Since this is now a dataset you can read the contents from the Foundry filesystem within your transform. I guess it will look something like this, note the `@transform` instead of `@transform_df`:

```py
   from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
   from pyspark.sql import Row


    @transform(
        out=Output("/US Office/COO/pdf_tests/datasets/pdf_read"),
        source_df=Input("/US Office/COO/pdf_tests/pdf_staset"),
    )
    def compute(ctx, source_df, out):
    
        rows = []
    
        with source_df.filesystem().open(latest_file.path, 'rb') as f:
            result = tabula.read_pdf(f.read(), pages='all')
    
            # add your logic to populate rows here:
            rows.append(Row({
               "col_a": "a",
               "col_b": "row",
               "col_c": "some values"
            }))
    
        schema = StructType([
            StructField('col_a', StringType()),
            StructField('col_b', StringType()),
            StructField('col_c', StringType()),
        ])
        return out.write_dataframe(ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(rows, schema))
```

I didn't test the code above.

Comment: So I tried the code with latest_file being 'test.pdf' and removing the .path since it didn't have that attribute. The error I am getting now is 'ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path'

I tried commenting out the code so I could use the filesystem list function in the debug console but since preview doesn't support input datasets without a schema I couldn't do that. It feels like we're close but I can't seem to get passed it. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are some results on SO around that value error. like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977519/valueerror-embedded-null-character-when-using-open/33981557 maybe it's worth taking a look.

Regarding logging, I think prints or logger outputs show up in your build logs on the build job, after you try to build. It's a bit slower, given the checks + build cycle, but maybe you can see your print debug outputs there?