# Discord bot unable to send images

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

*New to coding so please forgive if stupid mistakes / questions.

Trying to code my own discord bot, one of the commands it generates an image on my laptop from stable diffusion, I'm having trouble uploading the image.

code tried:

```
if p_message == 'test':
        return discord.File("D:\Work\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\outputs\txt2img-images\2023-07-28\00010-3821944730.png")
```

returns no error but in terminal says "embedded null character"

Also tried:

```
if p_message == 'test':
        return channel.send(discord.File("D:\Work\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\outputs\txt2img-images\2023-07-28\00010-3821944730.png"))
```

says 'channel' is undefined.

Also tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File("D:\Work\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\outputs\txt2img-images\2023-07-28\00010-3821944730.png"))
```

says 'channel' is undefined.

This is probably a dumb error on my end, also I'm not sure how much code I should provide, so if I need to send rest of my code lmk.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "embedded null character" occurs when there are issues with the file path or file name. In your case, it might be caused by the backslashes (`\`) in the file path. In Python strings, the backslash is used as an escape character, and it might be causing problems in the file path.

- Use raw string literals by adding an `r` before the file path to ignore the escape characters:

```py
if p_message == 'test':
    return discord.File(r"D:\Work\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\outputs\txt2img-images\2023-07-28\00010-3821944730.png")
```

if that doesn't work try changing the backslashes to forwardslashes.

Regarding the "channel is undefined" error, it seems like a problem with the `ctx` object. Try something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    file = discord.File(r"D:\Work\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\outputs\txt2img-images\2023-07-28\00010-3821944730.png")
    await ctx.send(file=file)
```

Comment: adding the 'r' lead to the following message instead of uploading the image file "<discord.file.File object at 0x00000174576AC520>"

changing it to fowardslashes '/' lead to the following message instead of uploading the image file "<discord.file.File object at 0x0000028CA98993C0>"

seems like none of the fixes worked, thanks for the help though feels like a bit of progress from embedded null character haha

Comment: Could try this:
`@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    file_path = r"D:\Work\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\outputs\txt2img-images\2023-07-28\00010-3821944730.png"
    file = discord.File(file_path)
    await ctx.channel.send(file=file)
`

Comment: Also see if there are some other ways to solve this problem. This questions has a lot of ways i couldn't list all the answer, but check them out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977519/valueerror-embedded-null-character-when-using-open

Comment: forgot to mention in the last comment, tried the code you provided, got the same problem. instead of an image the following text was sent <discord.file.File object at 0x000002C5CDAC9A20>. I'll have a look at the link you sent, thanks :)